# How to center align columns nested in a column

Tags: html, css

Having troubles aligning these columns inside a section column.

Here is a screenshot of what's happening: https://gyazo.com/cfe7bfa58e98226d8e1718792631c035

And here's jsfiddle with all the required code: https://jsfiddle.net/8xxgn8vr/

```
<!-- Testimonials Section -->
<section id="testimonials" class="testimonials-section">
    <div class="container testimonials-container center-block">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1 class="">Testimonials</h1>
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="col-lg-6 testimonials">
                            Review 1
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6 testimonials">
                            Review 2
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6 testimonials">
                            Review 3
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6 testimonials">
                            Review 4
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>


.container.testimonials-container {
    margin: 0 50px 0 50px;
    width: auto;
}

.col-lg-6.testimonials {
    background: #E5E4DF;
    height: 500px;
    padding: 25px;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 50px 25px 50px 25px;
}

.testimonials-section {
    background: #F6F6F6;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

It's basically a section for reviews in index.html page and inside the section there will be 4 reviews which I want to be aligned in the center.

Thanks for all the help in advance.

Comment: Please add your code to your question

Comment: Done! Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using bootstrap I would suggest not altering directly the width of the grid elements, when you get a `col-lg-6` that is supposed to occupy half of a `row` and set it to be 300px, you will be throwing away bootstrap responsiveness and it will eventually give you a hard time adjusting to the other specifics of the `col-lg-6` class.

Since you mentioned you wanted to have 4 reviews all centered you could perhaps change your code to use a `col-lg-3` that divides the `row` into 4 equal parts. Check this [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lucaslazaro/8xxgn8vr/14/), but it would go like this:

HTML:

```
    <!-- Testimonials Section -->
    <section id="testimonials" class="testimonials-section">
        <div class="container testimonials-container center-block">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h1 class="">Testimonials</h1>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="testimonials">
                   Review 1
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="testimonials">
                   Review 2
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="testimonials">
                   Review 3
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="testimonials">
                   Review 4
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Updated CSS:

```
.container.testimonials-container {
    margin: 0 50px 0 50px;
    width: auto;
}

.testimonials {
    background: #E5E4DF;
    height: 500px;
    padding: 25px;
    margin: 50px 25px 50px 25px;
}

.testimonials-section {
    background: #F6F6F6;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Yeah I realized my mistake a bit ago, set it all to 3.
Thanks for the help! So the trick was to get rid of width and then separate col-md-3 testimonials class into 2 divs? Would it not work if it was just a single div with the class = "col-md-3 testimonials"?

Also, can I set min-width to the elements? Because on smaller screens the review divs have very small width so it would be hard to read 3 words per line.

Comment: @raimond I just separated the `testimonials` class from the `col-lg-3` class because you were altering the margin, so it would conflict with the col-lg-3 margin and then it wont necessarily fit 4 columns into one row, since the set margin was bigger than the one defined by bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add class "row" to the outer column? Works for me in your fiddle.

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 row">
                <h1 class="">Testimonials</h1>
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="col-lg-6 testimonials">
                            Review 1
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6 testimonials">
                            Review 2
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6 testimonials">
                            Review 3
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6 testimonials">
                            Review 4
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: You need to put row as direct parent of any sequence of columns to align them right. Edited in above. Keep in mind if you test in jsfiddle, col-lg is not gonna work bc the "window" is too small.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to fit 4 sections of lg-6 into a row of lg-12. Bootstrap is a grid system based on 12 parts. If you want the parts to align you always need to think about the 12 sections.

If you have only 4 reviews, you have to make sure you are using 12 divide by 4 = 3, so you need lg-3. 
If you have less than 4 parts but you still want them to take space of 4 parts you'll have to intervene with bootstrap. (there is a SO post about aligning a row)

Also in your css you are changing the width of the bootstraps' divs and that's not good. (also margin). Never do that ;)

Example with 4 divs:
(using inner div)
HTML:

```
<!-- Testimonials Section -->
<section id="testimonials" class="testimonials-section">
  <div class="container testimonials-container center-block">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h1 class="">Testimonials</h1>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div class="col-lg-3 testimonials">
            <div>
              Review 1
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 testimonials">
            <div>
              Review 2
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 testimonials">
            <div>
              Review 3
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 testimonials">
            <div>
              Review 4
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.container.testimonials-container {
  margin: 0 50px 0 50px;
  width: auto;
}

.testimonials div {
  height: 500px;
  background: #E5E4DF;
  padding: 25px;
  margin: 50px 25px 50px 25px;
}

.testimonials-section {
  background: #F6F6F6;
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6zjo6w4z/2/)

Comment: np, don't forget to mark as answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
.col-lg-6.testimonials {
    background: #E5E4DF;
    height: 500px;
    padding: 25px;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 50px 25px 50px 25px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
.testimonials-section {
    background: #F6F6F6;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}



.testimonials {
 background: #FFFFFF;
 

}

.testimonials_content{
 width: 95%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 border: thin black solid;
 height: 500px;
 background: #F5F5F5;
 padding: 25px;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 16px;

}
```

```html
 <section id="testimonials">
         <div class="container testimonials-container">
             <div class="row">
              <h1>Tetimonials</h1>
             
                          <div class="col-lg-3 testimonials">
                          <div class="testimonials_content">
                        Review 1
                       </div>
                       </div>
                       <div class="col-lg-3 testimonials">
                          <div class="testimonials_content">
                        Review 2
                       </div>
                       </div>
                       <div class="col-lg-3 testimonials">
                          <div class="testimonials_content">
                        Review 3
                       </div>
                       </div>
                       <div class="col-lg-3 testimonials">
                          <div class="testimonials_content">
                        Review 4
                       </div>
                       </div>
                       
              </div></div>
     </section>
```

you can't fit 4 sections into **lg-6** for that you have to take **lg-3**. and under it you can take div by giving `margin` or `width` as per your need.

hope this helps.